# Accelerometer Status is SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, calibration, sensormanager

I am using accelerometer data in my android project but I found the sensor's data is bit off. When I checked for event.accuracy it returns SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE. When I perform calibration using [Accelerometer Calibration](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=redpi.apps.accelerometercalibrationfree&hl=en&gl=US) app from playstore, the sensor starts giving accurate reading. My question is how did they apply the calibrated data to raw sensor data that I get corrected values in my app?